# What's proper technique for naming packages in an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, directory

Specifically, what's the proper etiquette/conventions and terms for the different directories in Android Studio `app` folder?

Within that directory there are three more directories including `java`, but within Java are four layers of directories labelled `com.test.cad.breadcrumbs`, where `breadcrumbs` is the name of the application. Originally, `test` was set because I was just learning Android Studio, but now that it's actually an app, what should it be refactored to? Is it a package name? Can someone clarify terminology?

For example - why is the first directory called `com`? Or `cad`?

[Image of File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50sul.jpg)

Comment: "Is it a package name?" -- `com.test.cad.breadcrumbs` is a package name. In Java, source files are located in a series of subdirectories based upon the package name. "what should it be refactored to?" -- buy a domain name. Then, use the reverse-domain-name convention for the base of the package name. For example, I own `commonsware.com`, and so my Android projects are all in packages starting with `com.commonsware`.

Comment: @CommonsWare So basically - a website name or creator's identifier?

Comment: One thing I might change is the location of your test pckgs. You can put them in a dir named test and mark it as the test src location in the project settings.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - Something like `com.mywebsite.cad.breadcrumbs` contains all of our content, then `com.mywebsite.cad.test` contains all of our tests?

Comment: "So basically - a website name or creator's identifier?" -- more specifically, something that is likely to be unique at the moment and is unlikely to have somebody else accidentally collide with in the future. Reverse-domain-name is the recommended pattern, as it meets both criteria.

Comment: @CommonsWare And the `cad` part? (I'll add this as an answer after if you don't have time - extremely helpful!).

Comment: Anything after the plausibly-unique part is up to you, so long as it results in a valid Java package name (e.g., don't try using a comma).

Comment: @CommonsWare Last question I promise - why does Android Studio default to `cad` before the name of the app?

Comment: In the new-project wizard, the values that you type into the "Application name" and "Company Domain" fields determine the default package name. You can change that by clicking the little "Edit" link on the far end side of the dialog. So, if you type in CAD as the "Application name", that will result in a `.cad` segment being added by default to the package name.

Comment: No, I'm speaking more about your file structure in the link. You would have a `src` dir under `app`. In `src` you'd have `main` and `androidTest` dirs each with a `java` dir. Your packages go there with the *same* names or both regular and test packages with the convention described above. `me.you...somepackage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare in the comments my question was answered.

Essentially, reverse domain name convention is used for the base of the package name. So if I'm "apple.com" then I use "com.apple". It must be likely to be unique at the moment and unlikely to have a collision in the future.

After this base, any java package name is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's well explained at Oracle documentation:
[Naming a Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)